# Use json object as variable in controller via ngResource

Tags: angularjs

I fetch json data via ngResource angular, it is easy to use in view by using `{{ }}` but i don't know how to put these json objects to variable.

```js
var workersServices = angular.module('workersServices', ['ngResource']);
workersServices.factory('Worker', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('workers/:workerId.json', {}, {
            query: {method:'GET', params:{workerId:'workers'}, isArray:true}
        });
    }]);


var workersControllers = angular.module('workersControllers', []);
workersControllers.controller('costsCtrl', ['$scope','Worker', function($scope, Worker) {
    $scope.workers = Worker.query();
  
         HERE I WANT NAME PROPERTY AT THAT SCOPE :
          **$scope.janeDoeName = workers[0].name;    ??? IT DOESNT WORK**
  }]);

JSON DATA    workers.json 

[
    {
        "id": "jane-doe",
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "department": "sales",
        "period": {
            "start": "2015-12-14",
            "finish": "2018-12-14",
            "periodOfNotice": false
        },
        "paymentHour": 20,
        "hours": 168
    }]
```

I just want to put chosen property from that json to $scope and use it later in some functions.

Comment: The part where you say IT DOESNT WORK looks promising, except you need to wait on the async data

Comment: Pylyp,  services works, i use json objects in view by using {{ }}.

Comment: you can't access thee data until it is received...use $resource callback. Look at errors in browser console .. will give you clues

Comment: also `$scope.workers != workers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a callback function in the query:

```
var workersControllers = angular.module('workersControllers', []);
workersControllers.controller('costsCtrl', ['$scope','Worker', function($scope, Worker) {
        $scope.workers = Worker.query(function(){
        $scope.janeDoeName = $scope.workers[0].name; 
    });
  }]);
```